# Tab App fluid width not working

Tags: fluid, fixed-width, facebook-canvas

I have a tab app set to fluid on both height and width.  Height is no problem ... it is the width that is not working so a good portion of my page (which is only 648px wide) is not showing up.  We intentionally set the width to be less than the max so we wouldn't have this problem.  To view you can go to the Arrow Fasteners page ... contest or like us to enter tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Tab Apps are only working with a fixed width: 520px. Only height is settable.

Fluid Width is only for Canvas Apps (apps.facebook.com/app-name), that's why these settings are prefixed with "Canvas" (Canvas Width, Canvas Height).

Mike

Answer (score 0):

Add your AppID and the following codes, above the closing body tag. It will work perfectly on tabs.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
fb_root = document.createElement( 'div' );
fb_root.id = 'fb-root';
try
{
    window.document.childNodes[0].appendChild( fb_root );
}
catch( error )
{
    window.document.body.appendChild( fb_root );
}

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
    appId  : '222222222222222', //your app ID
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    });

    //FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 520, height: 1400 });

    function getDocHeight() {
        var D = document;
        return Math.max(
            Math.max(D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight),
            Math.max(D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight),
            Math.max(D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight)
        );
    }

    var mySetSize = function() {
        var height = getDocHeight();
        FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 520, height: height });
        setTimeout( mySetSize, 200 );
    };
    setTimeout( mySetSize, 200 );
};

(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());


var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
    style = document.createElement('style'),
    rules = document.createTextNode('body { position: relative; max-width: 520px!important;width: 520px!important; overflow: hidden!important; margin: 0px!important; }');

style.type = 'text/css';
if(style.styleSheet)
    style.styleSheet.cssText = rules.nodeValue;
else style.appendChild(rules);
head.appendChild(style);

</script>
```